# How to proceed with ear build in maven2?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, ear, maven-ear-plugin

I very new to maven2. Till yesterday i was successful in building war from maven2. My next target is to build ear file for a war file including few of jar files as well.

Can you please help with that.  I would be greatly thankful.

Regards
Gnash-85

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134894/maven2-best-practice-for-enterprise-project-ear-file

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation of the [Maven EAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/) and in particular the section about [EAR Modules](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/modules.html), the examples and the [Usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/usage.html) page should be the reference. But  you might find [Because I always forget how to use maven-ear-plugin](http://agoncal.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/because-i-always-forget-how-to-use-maven-ear-plugin/) an easier starting point.

If you have a more specific problem, please make the question more specific.

Comment: I have created ear build as follows.
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.adp.ihub -DartifactId=iHubEAR -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-j2ee-simple.
After which Now i want to include a war file into it and 3 jar files. How to accomplish it.

Comment: @gnash-85: Did you read the link I suggested as starting point?

Comment: Can you please help me Pascal. I really confused.

Comment: @gnash-85: I'm sorry but I can't write the whole project for you (which is basically what you're asking) and I don't know what I can do for you beyond providing the resources I provided. The link I mentioned implements almost exactly what you're looking for.