# Build an ear using maven

Tags: java, maven-2, building, maven-ear-plugin

I am new with maven, i have a task to change building of an ear from ant build to maven build. Are somewhere some tutorials related to this, how to build an ear using maven ?

Please guide me if you know something related to this....

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Thanks a lot for posting, i read the given links, how i understood from there, the war file and the ejb jar should be deployed to artifactory (company repository), so that its could be added as dependency in pom file from ear.

Also an ear could contain more than one war file (because i believe that my ear will contain more than one war file) ?

Please let me know if i understood right this...

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369153/how-to-proceed-with-ear-build-in-maven2, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134894/maven2-best-practice-for-enterprise-project-ear-file

Answer (score 5):

You may use the [Maven EAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/)

Also, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134894/maven2-best-practice-for-enterprise-project-ear-file) is a related StackOverflow post that might be very helpful to you.