# how to create ear project using maven

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, ear, maven-archetype

I would like to create an ear project using Maven. What is the maven archetype that I should use? I tried org.jboss.spec.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-ear-webapp but it is specific for Jboss AS.

Thanks a lot

Comment: see if this post is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829961/create-complete-ear-project-with-maven-and-eclipse-helios. All you would need is a j2ee archetype (maven-archetype-j2ee-simple) and maven ear plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/) to generate EAR

Comment: Thanks but i think that the maven-archetype-j2ee-simple archetype isn't the best solution because it create the modules ear, ejbs, logging, primary source, project, projects, servlet, servelets. I would like to create only the modules ear, ejb and war.