# Creating EAR file using Maven

Tags: java, jsp, maven, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am facing an issue while creating EAR file using Maven of a Dynamic Web Project.

I have successfully created WAR file using `POM.xml` , but can anybody tell me how to write EAR script in `POM.xml` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: These SO topics might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829961/create-complete-ear-project-with-maven-and-eclipse-helios

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134894/maven2-best-practice-for-enterprise-project-ear-file

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow! you may find this link helpful to know how to properly ask questions correctly, so that they fit the expected community format: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It easy.
You need:

1. Root project, parent pom that have 2 modules - war and ear.
2. Move your war to war module
3. create ear module (add war as dependency)

You can use archetype:generate to create example of ear. For example archetype with id: 612.

> 612: remote -> org.jboss.spec.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-ear-webapp (An
>   archetype that generates a starter Java EE 6 webapp project for JBoss
>   AS 7. The project is an EAR, with an EJB-JAR and WAR)

If you don't need ejb - just delete it. In generated example ejb is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Check my archetype for maven, this is for Java EE 6

https://github.com/sjpuas/jee6-archetype