# how do I create a lib folder in an ear file and populate with jars using build.xml?

Tags: java, jar, ear, build.xml

So I am able to populate jar files directly into the ear file, but I am unable to create a lib folder and populate those jars into that folder. I am new to this so any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a tool to do the build?

Comment: well I am using ant to build the build.xml. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Why don't you just use maven? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829961/create-complete-ear-project-with-maven-and-eclipse-helios