# Eclipse not being able to find pom.xml location

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have an existing `maven` project that I am planning on deploying using `WebLogic` Server. Since I need an `ear` file for the same, I am following the steps to create a `jar module` and a `war module` which I later plan on including in a `parent module`. However, when I make a `jar` module, the moment the folder reflects in `eclipse`, I get an error regarding the `pom.xml`. The error says that `Project build error: Non-readable POM pom.xml    /*ProjectName*JARModule line 1  Maven pom Loading Problem`. Any idea why this is happening? The same happens when I try to create a `war` module as well. And till I dont have those two modules ready, I cannot proceed to making an `ear` module and including both. 
Help much appreciated! 
**UPDATE - ** Here is my `parent project pom.xml` (On which I right cliked and chose to create a new module named `projectnameJAR` and `projectnameWAR` and even `projectnameEAR`-

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Project_name</groupId>
<artifactId>Project_name</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Project_name</name>
<build>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                    <version>7.0</version> <!-- Put here the version of your Java EE app, in my case 7.0 -->
                    <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

          <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>Project_nameJARModule</module>
        <module>Project_nameWARModule</module>
        <module>Project_nameEARModule</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Following is the `pom` that was generated for the `JAR` module -

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>Project_name</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project_name</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>Project_nameJAR</groupId>
<artifactId>Project_nameJAR</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>CADJAR</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

And the `pom` generated for the `WAR` module -

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>Project_name</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project_name</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>Project_nameWAR</groupId>
<artifactId>Project_nameWAR</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Project_nameWAR Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>Project_nameWAR</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: And your pom.xml looks like what? And is stored where? It doesn't matter which package type you choose, until the pom is found and could be parsed as xml. I recommend to start with an easy example.

Comment: I have posted the `parent projects pom`. Please check my edit and let me know what you think. And the `pom` is located in the `parent directory`.

Comment: Please post your pom from the JARModule as well. According to your error message the pom cannot be read. In the same folder as your parent you need a dir called Project_nameJARModule with a pom.xml inside. Like Aurelien said. Is that the case?

Comment: Posted the `pom` for the `JAR and WAR` Modules I created. Both of them are giving the same error. And yes, the error does say that the `pom` is not accessible, Is it because I have possibly created the modules in the wrong way? And because they are not under the `parent project` but as different modules, in the package explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of head banging around, I decided to switch my workspace once and check. And ta-daa. That was it. The problem was solved. Eclipse for some reason was misbehaving in the workspace I had then. I created a newer workspace and tried the same thing and everything ran smooth. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Switching workspace to an unused one and back to the original one was enough for me. I didn't need to make a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I have a working multi-module project which works with eclipse and weblogic-10.3.6. Could you confirm that you've got the same tree structure ?

```
parent-module
|_module-war
|   |_pom.xml
|_module-jar
|  |_pom.xml
|_module-ear
|  |_pom.xml
|_pom.xml
```

The parent-module/module-ear/pom.xml looks like this.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>group-module-ear</groupId>
  <artifactId>module-ear</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.2</version>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>   
  <parent>
       <groupId>group.parent</groupId>
       <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1</version>  
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group-module-war</groupId>
        <artifactId>module-war</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>group-module-jar</groupId>
        <artifactId>module-jar</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
    </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <configuration>

        <defaultLibBundleDir>APP-INF/lib</defaultLibBundleDir>           
           <modules> 
             <webModule>
               <groupId>group-module-war</groupId>
               <artifactId>module-war</artifactId>
               <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
             </webModule>
             <jarModule>
               <groupId>group-module-jar</groupId>
               <artifactId>module-jar</artifactId>
               <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
             </jarModule>             
          </modules>          
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

  </build>

</project>
```

The parent-module/pom.xml looks like this :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ETIC_J</groupId>
  <artifactId>ETIC_J</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>  

   <properties>
           <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
           <artifactory.url>localhost:8080</artifactory.url>
   </properties>

    <modules>      
         <module>module-jar</module>   
         <module>module-war</module>         
         <module>metier-etic-ear</module>               
    </modules> 

</project>
```

Comment: are your `module-war`,`module-jar`,`module-ear` files WITHIN the `parent-module`? If so, then no. My `war`,`jar` and `ear` are outside the parent project. (parent project being the one I right clicked on and created the modules).

Comment: Thank you for all your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your pom's seems to be okay, so it's probably a path issue between your parent pom and his childs.

```
parent-module (i.e. your eclipse workspace)
|_Project_nameJARModule
|   |_pom.xml
|_Project_nameWARModule
|  |_pom.xml
|_Project_nameEARodule
|  |_pom.xml
|_pom.xml
```

This is the same tree as [@Aurelien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2342125/aurelien) already posted.
If you don't structure the tree like this, you have to define the parent and module path.

How it works:

```
<modules>
    <module>../path/to/your/child/module/</module>
</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>

    <!-- define the path to the parent -->
    <relativePath>../path/pom.xml</relativePath> 
</parent>
```

Otherwise the tree strucutre above is the default if you don't define a specific `<relativePath>`

Comment: You mean to say that the `JAR`,`WAR`,`EAR` `modules` are to be in the same workspace, right?

Comment: Thank you for all your help! :)