# Which Artifact to choose for a JAR maven Project?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-archetype

Im developping an application that contains too projects
1.EJB Maven Project: it's a JAR file contains my models (jpa entities) and my services (      session Bean)
2.WEB Maven project: project containing all Views

Im planing to and the EJB project to the Web project ( Dependecies)
My question is; while creating the Web project i choosed WEB APP artifact
is there a particular Artifact for the jar project?

Answer (score 0):

For EJB project use simple jar project. Look at EAR archetype: `org.jboss.spec.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-ear-webapp`

More about this in question [Maven2: Best practice for Enterprise Project (EAR file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134894/maven2-best-practice-for-enterprise-project-ear-file)