# maven - need to create ear bundle

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-ear-plugin

I have a maven project which currently creates a `war package` on build. Now I need to bundle it as an `ear project`. Any pointers on how to do this. I added the `m2e plugin` and modified the `pom.xml` file, but, i am not able to get the directory structure as expected. I need the `dir structure` as below

```
project-name
  - project-name.ear
  - pom.xml
  - project-name.war
  - projec-name.jar
  - META-INF/application.xml
```

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty much a duplication of [the following](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134894/maven2-best-practice-for-enterprise-project-ear-file)

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly recommend that you organize your project structure in proper Maven style:

```
project-name/
  - pom.xml  (POM of project-name, multi-module POM)
  + project-name-jar
    - pom.xml  (main app JAR)
  + project-name-web
    - pom.xml  (WAR project to construct WAR by project-name-jar etc)
  + project-name-ear
    - pom.xml  (EAR project to construct EAR by project-name-war etc)
```

Normally I will have another child project call `project-name-parent` which use as parent POM for the whole project.

In Maven, you don't and you shouldn't have `META-INF/application.xml` as part of your source.  It is generated dynamically base on configuration of `maven-ear-plugin`.