# Eclipse: Import "Existing Maven Projects" create EAR project automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, m2e

I have a bizarre behavior with Eclipse when I try to import an existing maven project, it's a multi-module JEE maven project with a parent and sub-modules.
The structure svn looks like this:

- parent

  - ear
  - webapp1
  - webapp2
  - shared-library

When I import the project into Eclipse, it automatically create a "shared-libraryEAR" in the same directory of the "parent" project. It looks something like this after the import:

- shared-libraryEAR
- parent

  - ear
  - webapp1
  - webapp2
  - shared-library

It does this for every "jar" maven projects in the workspace.
It's something normal ? 
I use Eclipse Oxygen.2 and Eclipse Neon.3 with WebSphere plugins and the default embedded maven.

I can reproduce the same behavior using the demo project in this Stackoverflow answer: [Maven2: Best practice for Enterprise Project (EAR file)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28161000/1582541)

After importing the project into Eclipse Oxygen, I have two new EAR project that did not exist in the original project structure.
The structure in Eclipse Enterprise Explorer looks like this after the import:

- myproject-application (original ear) ¸
- myproject-business (original ejb)
- myproject-common (original jar lib)
- myproject-commonEAR (new EAR)
- myproject-persistence (original jar lib)
- myproject-persistenceEAR (new EAR)
- myproject-web (original web module)
- parent (original parent project)

Result in eclipse:
[Image capture of Eclipse Enterprise Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWRIK.png)

After importing the projects, I usually just delete the unnecessary EAR projects, but it's kind of annoying, is there a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make an example project with the structure and pom files etc. ?

Comment: I used the project from this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28161000/1582541

Comment: I found unchecking `Maven > Java EE Integration > Enable Java EE Configuration` worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying a fresh copy of eclipse (the same version) solved my problem regarding to this case. I guess, it happened because of a plugin on eclipse.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I find out, it's the Websphere 7 plugin who does this. On a fresh eclipse install with only the Websphere 8 plugins installed, I don't have this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience and ran across https://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E-WTP/New_and_Noteworthy/1.1.0 .

> m2e-wtp can also be disabled via the m2e.wtp.activation>false in the Maven  section of your project pom;xml.

I create a new workspace and cloned a fresh copy of my code in a temp directory. I then updated the parent pom.xml with the following:

```
    <properties>
        <m2e.wtp.activation>false</m2e.wtp.activation>
        <m2e.jaxrs.activation>false</m2e.jaxrs.activation>
        <m2e.jpa.activation>false</m2e.jpa.activation>
        <m2e.jsf.activation>false</m2e.jsf.activation>
        <m2e.cdi.activation>true</m2e.cdi.activation>
    </properties>
```

I then imported `Existing Maven Projects` and no extra EAR projects.

Comment: Unfortunately, this prevents m2e from turning the project into a faceted web project (WTP) and then it doesn't work well with Eclipse JEE tooling.

Answer (score 0):

This ill behaviour is the result of having IBM's WebSphere plugins for Eclipse.

Removing these plugins from Eclipse, or starting with a fresh Eclipse install (like the accepted answer suggests), is not sufficient.

You will also need to create a new Eclipse workspace.

I haven't got the time yet to figure out why, but that's the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences>Java EE>Project>Enterprise Application Membership>Add project to an EAR

uncheck that checkbox to avoid the creation of EAR projects.