# how to configure Wildfly to deploy Maven project

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

I'm learning Maven with eclipse and a liitle bit confused on how to deployed it on a remote server.
Before using Maven I created a web project and exported it as ear file and copied to the server's deployment folder. With Maven do I follow the same step? Do I need to install maven at wildfly server by modify the configuration xml? Thx.

Comment: Do not use a build tool to execute the application! Configure maven to produce whatever artifact you need (`jar`, `war`, `ear`,...) and copy that to the remote server. Preferably through a deployment pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Use maven only to produce artifacts(jar, war, ear). I was in the same position a couple of years back and found a useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134894/maven2-best-practice-for-enterprise-project-ear-file) to build a project as an `ear` with maven.
For the remaining tasks, I coded Shell script to move the artifact from `/target` directory to wildfly10 `\standalone\deployments`.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be achieved without any script using symbolic links.Just `cd` to your \standalone\deployments directory and:

```
ln -s [ABSOULUTE-PATH-TO-YOUR-WAR/EAR-FILE] [NAME-OF-EAR]
```

That's it. If you are more interested in symbolic links you may read [here](https://www.shellhacks.com/symlink-create-symbolic-link-linux/)