# Jars to be included automatically while publishing the server

Tags: java, wildfly-8

I have some jars which are needed by the web application, so whenever i clean the wildfly server from eclipse the server publishes the code back in the deployment folder of the server, and once the server has published, the jars need to be manually copied and pasted back in the **deployments/project.ear/lib**.

Is there a way to automate it, like if the server is cleaned then also copy the jars while publishing the server back.
Or can it be configured through eclipse?

Comment: If you aren't using maven, I'd suggest moving to it.

Comment: Oh, anyother way by which it can be done, its like 60 project, so doing it will take a while., or can we have a common pom file by which it can be done?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134894/maven2-best-practice-for-enterprise-project-ear-file